# Select 2nd and 3rd newest row in an SQL table

Tags: sql

i'm currently developing a news-site.
So here is the problem. I want to select the 2nd and 3rd row in a TOP 3.

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM News ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

I want to remove the 1st row and only return the 2nd and 3rd row.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Depends on **which concrete database system** you're using! Please always mention that - SQL is just the query language - not a database product....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 FROM
( SELECT TOP 3 * FROM News ORDER BY Date DESC ) xx
ORDER BY Date
```

SQLFiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbb7e/5

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this generically using window functions:

```
select n.*
from (SELECT n.*, row_number() over (order by date desc) as seqnum
      FROM News n
     ) n
where n.seqnum >= 2 and n.seqnum <= 3;
```

I just offer this as a general solution.  You can also ensure that you get everything from the second date (in case there are more than two items on that date) by using `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`.

Comment: Did you mean `where seqnum >= 2 and seqnum <= 3`?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that no two dates will be the same, you could add

```
where date not in (select max(date) from News)
```

Or you could look at `rowid` if you know that the first item will have rowid=0, for example if you created a temp table with the results of your initial query.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you somehow know what you Top 3 news are by ordering by date descending.
Therfore you should use the LIMIT clause with an OFFSET [For sqlite]

```
SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1;
```

Comment: LIMIT x OFFSET y is a mySQL variation, while TOP 3 is MS-SQL.

Comment: am kinda new to this. But can you use this in MSSQL?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select top 2 * from News cross apply (select top 3 from news order by date desc)x
```